# Displaying an activity as a dialog in android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I would like to display an activity as a dialog like this app here.How can i do that?I have tried a custom layout for a dialog but it doesnt look like the xml output.[image]

Comment: Add padding to the Layout of the activity maybe. Else you can use DialogFragment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use DialogFragment or use AlertDialog as below:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutRoot));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(layout);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as this is not an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your manifest in your `Activity` declaration.

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding this in your mainfest in the activity you want to show as a Dialog will help you:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

set the theme of your activity to the theme of a dialog

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

then in your activity dont set any view and just create a dialog with the view you want to show